# Missing Component "MainActivity" Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-intent, xamarin.android

I am trying to complete [this tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/mobile/BackgroundLocationDemo/) in my application. Since I have a PCL App.cs, I attempted to add that code to my `MainActivity.cs.` However, when I build the project, it appears that either my `MainActivity` is missing or my manifest is not correct.

**MainActivity.cs**

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Plugin.Messaging;
using Plugin.Permissions;
using Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Divco.Droid
{
[Activity(Label = "Divco.Droid", Icon = "@drawable/logo_size_icon", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    public event EventHandler<ServiceConnectedEventArgs> LocationServiceConnected = delegate { };

    protected static LocationServiceConnection locationServiceConnection;

    public static MainActivity Current
    {
        get { return current; }
    }
    private static MainActivity current;

    public LocationService LocationService
    {
        get
        {
            if (locationServiceConnection.Binder == null)
                throw new Exception("Service not bound yet");
            // note that we use the ServiceConnection to get the Binder, and the Binder to get the Service here
            return locationServiceConnection.Binder.Service;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

        Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, bundle);

        CrossMessaging.Current.Settings().Phone.AutoDial = true;

        LoadApplication(new App());

        MainActivity.StartLocationService();
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    //public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
    //{
    //    PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    //}

    public static void StartLocationService()
    {
        // create a new service connection so we can get a binder to the service
        locationServiceConnection = new LocationServiceConnection(null);

        // this event will fire when the Service connectin in the OnServiceConnected call 
        locationServiceConnection.ServiceConnected += (object sender, ServiceConnectedEventArgs e) => {

            Console.WriteLine("Service Connected");
        };

        // Starting a service like this is blocking, so we want to do it on a background thread
        new Task(() => {

            // Start our main service
            Console.WriteLine("App", "Calling StartService");
            Android.App.Application.Context.StartService(new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(LocationService)));

            // bind our service (Android goes and finds the running service by type, and puts a reference
            // on the binder to that service)
            // The Intent tells the OS where to find our Service (the Context) and the Type of Service
            // we're looking for (LocationService)
            Intent locationServiceIntent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(LocationService));
            Console.WriteLine("App", "Calling service binding");

            // Finally, we can bind to the Service using our Intent and the ServiceConnection we
            // created in a previous step.
            Android.App.Application.Context.BindService(locationServiceIntent, locationServiceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate);
        }).Start();
    }

    public static void StopLocationService()
    {
        // Check for nulls in case StartLocationService task has not yet completed.
        Console.WriteLine("App", "StopLocationService");

        // Unbind from the LocationService; otherwise, StopSelf (below) will not work:
        if (locationServiceConnection != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("App", "Unbinding from LocationService");
            Android.App.Application.Context.UnbindService(locationServiceConnection);
        }

        // Stop the LocationService:
        if (Current.LocationService != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("App", "Stopping the LocationService");
            Current.LocationService.StopSelf();
        }
    }
}
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="9" android:versionName="0.1" package="com.divcodelivery.divco">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER" />
    <application android:label="Divco" android:icon="@drawable/logo_size_icon"></application>
</manifest>
```

Here are my results when I attempt to build to my phone:

> am start -n "com.divcodelivery.divco/md58047ec786dcfdff107cc37976c308625.MainActivity"
>   Starting: Intent { cmp=com.divcodelivery.divco/md58047ec786dcfdff107cc37976c308625.MainActivity }
>   Error type 3
>   Error: Activity class {com.divcodelivery.divco/md58047ec786dcfdff107cc37976c308625.MainActivity} does not exist.
>
> Failed to launch app: Device could not find component named: com.divcodelivery.divco/md58047ec786dcfdff107cc37976c308625.MainActivity

Comment: Delete the apk from the device/emulator (`adb uninstall com.divcodelivery.divco` or via the device's Settings), Clean & BuildAll (so Xamarin will re-install the complete app) and start a new debugging session.

Comment: @SushiHangover I had uninstalled it and done that before... but after uninstalling through adb, cleaning, and building (and perhaps your good vibes), IT WORKED! Thank you so much!

Comment: It does this regularly on Visual Studio 2015. Never have any issues on VS2012.

Comment: I've had the similar issue recently, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/514041/xamarinforms-not-found-mainactivity-for-android-8.html?childToView=514120#answer-514120

Comment: @sushihangover you should add your comment as an answer so it can be accepted. Helped me out - and I thank you!